# Distance between plane and point.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the point in the plane $2x-y+2z = 16$ that is closest to the origin and calculate the distance from the origin to this point.

This type of question is on here... multiple times.

But I already know how to find the shortest distance, it's the straight line distance between the point and the plane, such that the line is normal to the plane. So we find the projection of the line $\vec{PP_0}$ onto a unit normal and we are done. We get $\frac{16}{3}$.
Or we could find a parametric line through the point (origin in this case), and find the parameter $t=16/9$  and get point 1/9(32,-16,32), the magnitude of which is $\frac{16}{3}$ that is the distance between the origin and the point, now my question is, is there another method?

The question this post is about is placed inside a section on local extreme values, Lagrange multipliers have not been covered yet!. So I am a little confused as to go about doing this.

I would not usually be worried about this but the following question asks

$$\text{What point on the elliptical cone } z = (x^{2}+2y^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \text{is closest to the point} (1,2,0)?$$

I can no longer use previous methods(I will have to think about that, I may be able to use $grad(f)$).

Sorry for the long post, did not want people to think I was being lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the distance between a plane and a point, the previous answer is top notch.

As for the distance between a cone (or other surface) and a point, you can use the same method: $P = (x,y,z)$ is on the surface, $P_0 = (1,2,0)$ is given. In this case,
$$f = \rho^2(P, P_0) = (x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 + (x^2+2y^2) \to min$$
$f$ is a convex function. Necessary extremum condition is $\nabla f = 0$, that is 
$$f_x = 0 \\ f_y = 0$$ which yields the cone point $(1/2, 2/3, (1/4+8/9)^{1/2})$ is this case.

Answer (score 0):

> is there another method?

Let $(a,2a+2b-16,b)$ be a point on $2x-y+2z=16$.

Now we have
$$\begin{align}&a^2+(2a+2b-16)^2+b^2\\&=a^2+4a^2+4b^2+256+8ab-64a-64b+b^2\\&=5a^2+(8b-64)a+5b^2-64b+256\\&=5\left(\left(a+\frac{4b-32}{5}\right)^2-\left(\frac{4b-32}{5}\right)^2\right)+5b^2-64b+256\\&=5\left(a+\frac{4b-32}{5}\right)^2-5\left(\frac{4b-32}{5}\right)^2+5b^2-64b+256\\&=5\left(a+\frac{4b-32}{5}\right)^2+\frac 95\left(b-\frac{32}{9}\right)^2+\frac{256}{9}\end{align}$$

So, solving
$$a+\frac{4b-32}{5}=b-\frac{32}{9}=0$$
gives the point we want : $(\frac{32}{9},-\frac{16}{9},\frac{32}{9})$ and the distance $\sqrt{\frac{256}{9}}=\frac{16}{3}$.